# How to apply some operations on only specific items in the list in Python or pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

I have two lists:

```
main = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,20]
replace_items = [6,8,20]
```

I want this replace items to replace with replace_items*10 i.e [60, 80,200]

So the result main list would be:

```
main = [1,2,3,4,5,60,7,80,200]
```

My trial:

I am getting an error:

```
for t in replace_items:
    for o in main:
       
        main = o.replace(t, -(t-100000), regex=True)

        print(main)
```

following is the error I am getting:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-592-d3f3f6915a3f> in <module>
     14         main = o.replace(t, -(t-100000), regex=True)
---> 15         print(main)
     
            

TypeError: replace() takes no keyword arguments
```

Comment: Try the [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) guide?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use list comprehension:

```
main = [x * 10 if x in replace_items else x for x in main]
```

Output:

```
print(main)
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 60, 7, 80, 200]
```

Answer (score 0):

As you initially had a `pandas` tag, you might be interested in a vectorial solution.

Here using numpy

```
import numpy as np

main = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,20])
replace_items = np.array([6,8,20])  # a list would work too

main[np.in1d(main, replace_items)] *= 10
```

output:

```
>>> main
array([  1,   2,   3,   4,   5,  60,   7,  80, 200])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```py
for (index,mainItems) in enumerate(main) : 
    if mainItems in replace_items : 
        main[index] *= 10
```

By using `enumerate(main)` you have access to both index and item

Answer (score 0):

Using `pandas` you can do

```
import pandas as pd
main = pd.Series([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,20])
replace_items = [6,8,20]
main[main.isin(replace_items)] *= 10
print(main.values)
```

Output

```
[  1   2   3   4   5  60   7  80 200]
```

Explanation: use [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) to find elements which are one of `replace_items`, `something *= 10` is concise way to write `something = something * 10`